# Sockets con Java (servidor) y Python (cliente) sin flush en python

Tags: java, python, socket, stream

Hola tengo un proyecto de sockets (práctica por ahora) y el problema es que del lado del cliente (en python) no se como puedo limpiar o algo similiar el buffer de salida del socket. El primer mensaje se envia "correctamente", ya que es el primero y no hay nada en el socket (por decirlo de alguna manera), pero el siguiente mensaje se envia con el mensaje anterior, y el siguiente mensaje con anterior más el anterior, y asi sucesivamente.

Tengo un servidor simple en Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class serpy {

    static int port = 2018;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Esperando cliente");
        Socket cli = server.accept();

        String recibido = "", enviado = "";

        OutputStreamWriter outw = new OutputStreamWriter(cli.getOutputStream(), "UTF8");
        InputStreamReader inw = new InputStreamReader(cli.getInputStream(), "UTF8");

        char[] cbuf = new char[512];

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Esperando mensaje del cliente en python");
            inw.read(cbuf);
            for (char c : cbuf) {
                recibido += c;
                if (c == 00) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Cliente dice: " + recibido);
            System.out.println("Enviar a cliente: >>>" + recibido);
            recibido = "S:" + recibido;

            outw.write(recibido.toCharArray());
            outw.flush();

            cbuf = new char[512];

        }

    }
}
```

Ejemplo de ejecución del servidor en java:

> Esperando cliente
>   Esperando mensaje del cliente en python
>   Cliente dice: haha
>   Enviar a cliente: >>>haha
>   Esperando mensaje del cliente en python
>   Cliente dice: S:haha
>   Enviar a cliente: >>>S:haha
>   Esperando mensaje del cliente en python
>   Cliente dice: S:S:haha
>   Enviar a cliente: >>>S:S:haha
>   Esperando mensaje del cliente en python
>   Cliente dice: S:S:S:haha
>   Enviar a cliente: >>>S:S:S:haha
>   Esperando mensaje del cliente en python

Y el cliente esta en Python, simple igual:

```
import sys
import socket as sk

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 2018

sCliente =  sk.socket()
sCliente.connect((host, port))
print("Conectado")
inp = input("Texto para enviar:")
out = inp.encode("UTF8")
print("Se ha enviado: " + str(out.decode("UTF-8")))
sCliente.send(out)
seguir = True
while seguir:
    ins = sCliente.recv(512)
    insd = ins.decode("UTF8")
    print("Servidor retorna: " + str(insd))
    inp = input("Texto para enviar:")
    print("Enviar " + str(inp))
    salida = inp.encode("UTF8")
    print("Salida tiene antes de enviar: " + str(salida.decode("utf8")))
    lene = sCliente.send(salida)
    print("Se han enviado: " + str(lene) + " :bytes al servidor")
    if inp == "exit":
        seguir = False
    #salida = None
    ins = ""
sCliente.close()
print("Terminado")
```

Salida de ejecución de python:

> Texto para enviar:haha
>   Se ha enviado: haha
>   Servidor retorna: S:haha
>   Texto para enviar:as
>   Enviar as
>   Salida tiene antes de enviar: as
>   Se han enviado: 2 :bytes al servidor
>   Servidor retorna: S:S:haha as
>   Texto para enviar:aa
>   Enviar aa
>   Salida tiene antes de enviar: aa
>   Se han enviado: 2 :bytes al servidor
>   Servidor retorna: S:S:S:haha as aa
>   Texto para enviar:wqe
>   Enviar wqe
>   Salida tiene antes de enviar: wqe

La comunicación se da correctamente el problema, repito, es ¿Como puedo limpiar el "buffer" del socket cliente en Python para que me envie solo el mensaje nuevo y no todo lo que se ha enviado?.

Lo hago con esos objetos en Java, por que quiero que el intercambio de mensajes sea meramente en bytes para utilizar el UTF8.

Lo practiqué solo con Python y no me daba este problema, no sé si el error será del lado de Python.

**Básicamente:**

- ¿Cómo limpiar el buffer del socket creado desde python para enviar un nuevo mensaje? De ser el problema en Python.
- Si fuese en la parte de Java, toda recomendación y consejo me será de mucha ayuda.

Comment: El problema no es de sockets; los sockets sencillamente no hacen eso. Está en tu código.

Comment: no hacen que? no es de mucha ayuda su comentario, en python (cliente- servidor) no me daba ese problema, enviaba lo que que tenia que enviar pero aplicandolo a java me pasa eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no está en el código Python ni en el funcionamiento de los sockets, está en el código Java. En ningún momento limpias tu variable `recibido`, solo concatenas los nuevos bytes recibidos a los que ya tenias. Por lo que el eco enviado al cliente no es el mensaje recibido en ese momento sino la concatenación de todos los anteriores. Simplemente haz que `recibido` sea una cadena vacía al empezar cada lectura como haces en Python con `ins` (que por otra parte, no es necesario):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class serpy {

    static int port = 2018;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Esperando cliente");
        Socket cli = server.accept();

        String recibido = "", enviado = "";

        OutputStreamWriter outw = new OutputStreamWriter(cli.getOutputStream(), "UTF8");
        InputStreamReader inw = new InputStreamReader(cli.getInputStream(), "UTF8");

        char[] cbuf = new char[512];

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Esperando mensaje del cliente en python");
            inw.read(cbuf);
            for (char c : cbuf) {
                recibido += c;
                if (c == 00) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Cliente dice: " + recibido);
            System.out.println("Enviar a cliente: >>>" + recibido);
            recibido = "S:" + recibido;


            outw.write(recibido.toCharArray());
            outw.flush();
            recibido = "";

            cbuf = new char[512];
        }
    }
}
```

Te dejo el código de Python simplificado por si te interesa:

```
import sys
import socket as sk

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 2018

sCliente =  sk.socket()
sCliente.connect((host, port))
print("Conectado")

while True: 
    inp = input("Texto para enviar: ")
    print("Enviar:", inp)
    salida = inp.encode("UTF8")
    print("Salida antes de enviar:", salida.decode("utf8"))
    lene = sCliente.send(salida)
    print("Se han enviado: {} bytes al servidor.".format(lene))   
    ins = sCliente.recv(512)
    insd = ins.decode("UTF8")
    print("Servidor retorna:", insd)
    if inp == "exit":
        break

sCliente.close()
print("Terminado")
```

Comment: Gracias!!! (Y)
Si lo del ins era para iniciarlizar todas las variables (por aquello) pero no lo hice con la que era jajaja